# PHP-MYSQL Every time a specific row hits it adds +1 to PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

Here's what I currently have to get the values from database

```
$unread_messages = "";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE msg_to='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' or
msg_from='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$msg_id = $row["msg_id"];
$msg_to = $row["msg_to"];
$msg_from = $row["msg_from"];
$msg_title = $row["msg_title"];
$msg_content = $row["msg_content"];
$msg_date = $row["msg_date"];
$msg_read = $row["msg_read"];
}
```

now I need it so that everytime '$msg_read == 1' it adds +1 to '$unread_messages'. Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a check in your loop

```
$unread_messages = 0;

while ( ... ) {
    // do stuff
    if ($msg_read == 1) {
        $unread_messages++;
    }
}
```

---

I highly recommend that you take a look at the [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extensions for database access.  `mysql_` is outdated and should not be used.

Comment: +1 for mysql or PDO. The only comment actually not hunting for easy reputation and helping out the newcomer. Well done.

Comment: thanks a lot. I've always been told to use PDO, so what's the difference? Does mysql_ have security issues ?

Comment: Yes, there are some issues with `mysql_`.  It does not support prepared statements and is considered 'deprecated'.  In fact, the internal PHP team has been discussing how to get people to stop using `mysql_` and use the newer, more secure, feature-rich extensions.  New code should definitely not be written using this outdated extension.

Comment: thanks guys and thanks for the great answers I'll start reading [this](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this one ?

```
$unread_messages = "";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE msg_to='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' or
msg_from='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$msg_id = $row["msg_id"];
$msg_to = $row["msg_to"];
$msg_from = $row["msg_from"];
$msg_title = $row["msg_title"];
$msg_content = $row["msg_content"];
$msg_date = $row["msg_date"];
$unread_messages = ($row["msg_read"]==1 && $unread_messages=='') ? $unread_messages=1 : $unread_messages=$unread_messages+1;
}
```

ohh, im sorry, using PDO actualy really good practice, may be you can try this

```
$unread_messages = "";
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dbname", $username, $password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pm WHERE msg_to='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' or msg_from='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' LIMIT 10";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row){
        $unread_messages = ($row["msg_read"]==1 && $unread_messages=='') ? $unread_messages=1 : $unread_messages=$unread_messages+1;
    }
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think I'm going to switch to PDO instead of mysql_

Comment: Thanks this is perfect all my programming skills are self-taught so I have to take time to learn PDO. This will help me learn the syntax better thanks Wenkhairu.

Answer (score 0):

```
$unread_message = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{  
   //Your code
   if ($msg_read === 1)
       $unread_message++;
}
```

Comment: `=== 1` will always fail in this context as far as I know, values read from database are usually not automatically converted to int datatype!